# How to load images for UITableView or UICollectionView from cache everytime

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, caching, uicollectionview

I am struggling to figure out how to make images load from the cache every time I refresh an UITableView or an UICollectionView. I have tried 6 different frameworks for loading and caching images including SDWebImage, DFImageManager to name a few with no results. I even added cache headers for all the image with a max-age for a year and that didn't even work. No matter which framework I use, it will only load from the remote and not from the cache. But when running the app in offline mode, images will appear extremely quickly. Is there something that I am missing? Any code suggestions for lazy loading?

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(DiscoverCollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (cell.merchant.image) {
    cell.backgroundImageView.image = cell.merchant.image;
} else {
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    cell.imageOperation = [manager downloadImageWithURL:cell.merchant.imageUrl options:SDWebImageRefreshCached progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)cacheType);
        if (image) {
            cell.backgroundImageView.image = image;
            cell.merchant.image = image;
        }
    }];
} }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(DiscoverCollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (cell.imageOperation) {
    [cell.imageOperation cancel];
}
cell.imageOperation = nil; }
```

I am performing the download in the willDisplayCell using SDWebImage. Now when NSLogging the cacheType, it is always zero meaning that it is being downloaded from remote and not from the cache.

Comment: could you show some codes on how you do the caching?

Comment: If you are using local DB then save everything in it and run SQL query with date, then the caching will be from local DB. It will act as cache if you are using Sqlite. A code snippet will help us check the problem

Comment: I updated my question with a code snippet of how I am doing caching using SDWebImage.